# Calculating sum of a certain group of integers in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

So im very new to python and am trying to make a text based rpg-like thing that involves a first room with 2 exits (left or right) and each row of rooms afterwards has the amount of integers of the sum of the last one and each variable is a random integer from 0 to 3(amount of exits), like so:

```
a = [2]
print(a)
import random
b = []
for i in range(0,2):
    x = random.randint(0,3)
    b.append(x)
print(b)
b_sum = sum(b)
import random
c = []
for i in range(0,b_sum):
    x = random.randint(0,3)
    c.append(x)
print(c)
c_sum = sum(c)
import random
d = []
for i in range(0,c_sum):
    x = random.randint(0,3)
    d.append(x)
print(d)
d_sum = sum(d)
import random
e = []
for i in range(0,d_sum):
    x = random.randint(0,3)
    e.append(x)
print(e)
e_sum = sum(e)
import random
f = []
for i in range(0,e_sum):
    x = random.randint(0,3)
    f.append(x)
print(f)
f_sum = sum(f)
import random
g = []
for i in range(0,f_sum):
    x = random.randint(0,3)
    g.append(x)
print(g)
```

This works fine however navigation has proven hard.

```
rowlist = [a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,ii]
row = (rowlist[0])

room = (a[0])
print(room)
if room == 2:
    door=str(input("left or right"))
    if door == "left":
        roomsum = sum(row[row < room (+1)])
```

What i am attempting to do here is finding the sum of every integer in the list that comes before the current 'room'. But i have no idea how to do this! Any help would be appreciated, many thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO! There is a lot of repeated code here. This is an indicator of a design problem that can be solved with a data structure. Why not use a dictionary with letter keys pointing to each list? Why `import random` repeatedly? Once is enough, at the top of the file. I recommend providing more context for what you're trying to do and showing the exact output structure you want. Thanks.

Comment: Try replacing the last line with `roomsum = sum(row[:room])`, this line uses splicing to consider all elements before `room`

Comment: no idea what you are trying to do. not able to understand your reasoning. you get lots of 1 element lists that contain something between 0 and 3., stuff those lists in another list, calculate a lot of 1-element-list-sums (wich are all the same as X at that time) then you try to sum something from the list of lists wich looks as if it should throw an error ... or produce the same as the value inside a list or no idea what it does... - voting to close as unclear

Comment: @patrick None of the lists are 1 element dont know what youre getting at there. each list has as many elements as the sum of the last list

Comment: @ggorlen As i said, i am **very** new to python and dont know how to do that. I dont know why people are downvoting me for simply being bad at python, im asking for help after all

Comment: Don't take offense at a downvote or two--we've all been new and been through that, so nobody is judging you (or they shouldn't be, anyway). The difficulty here is that it's unclear what you're trying to achieve. Can you show the desired output structure with an explanation of how you want to produce it? You can edit your post to try to clarify your goal and specification. Thanks.

Comment: @ggloren I dont exactly know what youre asking but basically i want to have a series of rows where each is represented by a list of random integers 0 - 3. these integers representing the amount of exits that room has the next row has the amount of elements as the sum of the last row. This works fine, but what i am struggling with is navigating through this. i picked choosing left as my first option and wanted it to then make the room the sum of all integers before the current room; which ive mostly figured out, but in the next row on. which was why i put all the lists(rows) into a list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems as if you are looking for something like:

```
import random

big_list = [[2]]

for _ in range(1,5):  # increase to create more "rooms"
    big_list.append( [random.randint(0,3) for _ in range(sum(big_list[-1]))])

total = 0
for inner in big_list:
    print(inner, "before:", total)
    total += sum(inner)
```

To produce lists like:

```
[2] before: 0
[3, 1] before: 2
[2, 3, 1, 1] before: 6
[1, 1, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2] before: 13
[2, 3, 0, 2, 3, 2, 2, 1, 0, 2] before: 23
```

Due to randomness you also might get:

```
[2] before: 0
[0, 1] before: 2
[0] before: 3
[] before: 3
[] before: 3
```

---

A partial sum inside a list can be got by a generator expression inside sum or list slicing and sum:

```
lol = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12], [13,14,15,16,17]]

idx_in_lol   = 1      # [4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]

idx_in_inner = 5      # [4,5,6,7,8,***9***,10,11,12]

# generator expression and enumerate     
s1 = sum( i if idx < idx_in_inner else 0 for idx,i in enumerate(lol[idx_in_lol]))

# or by slicing
s2 = sum( lol[idx_in_lol][:idx_in_inner] )

print(s1, s2)
```

Output:

```
30 30 #  4+5+6+7+8 = 30
```

Comment: the list thing is right and i think it works better that mine but what are you getting at with the 'before: 0' thing

Comment: oh actualy i see now, the 'before' is the sum of every list before it. i perhaps didnt explain my goal well enough because that isnt quite what im after. you see i want is a way to determine the sum of every element before a particular element in one list. so say if the variable for what 'room' the character is in is the 5th room on the fourth list your provide and they choose to go left they should enter the 5th room on the next row because the sum of the first 4 elements in list 4 is 4. hope this makes sense!

Comment: @TedJ see edit. sum enumerate on generator expression or slice list

Comment: another quick question actually if you dont mind, how could i make the lists in 'lol', as you put it, the lists randomly generated in your first operation                : ```import random

big_list = [[2]]

for _ in range(1,5):
    big_list.append( [random.randint(0,3) for _ in range(sum(big_list[-1]))])```

Comment: @Ted? no idea what you mean. maybe you should paint a picture of how your rooms connect, why which room has how many exits and how you want them to be connected in a new question - or do some tutorials on lists and random to get to your goal

Comment: actually nevermind ive figured it out myself, sorry for bothering you! thanks a lot for your help i understand it much better now